# How do I work out the generator for $GL(2,\Bbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, trigonometry

Where $G$ is a group $$G=GL(2,\mathbb{R})$$

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\pi/4) & \sin(\pi/4)\\ 
-\sin(\pi/4)& \cos(\pi/4) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I work out the generator $\langle x\rangle$... Quite new to group theory so any help would help, thanks.

Comment: That's a rotation matrix. What are its powers?

Comment: What do you mean by rotation matrix?

Comment: In linear algebra, a rotation matrix is a matrix that is used to perform a rotation in Euclidean space. To learn more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix $x$ represents a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ around the origin by the angle $\frac{\pi}4$ clockwise.

In general $R(\phi) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ -\sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{bmatrix}$ does the same thing with the angle $\phi$.

Clearly if you rotate by $\phi$ and then by $\psi$, it is the same as rotating by $\phi + \psi$. Hence $R(\phi)R(\psi) = R(\phi + \psi)$. You can also check this algebraically, of course.

Also $R(\phi)^{-1} = R(-\phi)$ as the inverse of a rotation by $\phi$ is a rotation by $-\phi$.

Therefore

$$\langle x\rangle = \{x^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \left\{R\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} = \left\{R\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right) : n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

Hence your group consists of all rotations by an angle which is a multiple of $\frac\pi4$.

Comment: This is a great explanation thank you, although the book I'm reading says the answer is {e, x, x^2, x^3} how can I convert this notation? - @mechanodroid

Comment: @Reety Are you sure about that? Notice that $x^8 = R(\pi/4)^8 = R(2\pi) = e$ and the smaller powers are not equal to $e$ so the group should be $$\langle x\rangle = \{e,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7\}$$

Comment: @Reety: Which book are you using?

Comment: @Shaun I don't know what it's called since It's a pdf file and it doesn't have the author on it and the names generic.

Comment: @Reety: If you found it online, then copy & paste a long sentence from it into a search engine, with speechmarks both sides; it might show up.

Comment: @Shaun I can't because it's got all mathematical text in there so it doesn't come up with anything related.